# Overwriting Data in a C++ File using fstream

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hi i want to overwrite the content(object) in a specific file i have set the position but it always add to the end of the file

Code

```
 int InputIO::editPatient(int location,Obj P){

        int positon=location*sizeof(P);
        f.open("File.dat",ios::in|ios::out|ios::app|ios::binary|ios::ate);
        f.seekp(0,ios::beg);
        f.seekp(positon,ios::cur);
        f.write((char*)&P,sizeof(Movie));
        f.close();

        return 0;



        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solve this have to remove ios::app (Append) Append always add to the end of the file

Answer (score 6):

Don't use the `ios::app` flag (which stands for *append*).  When you use this flag, it prevents you from reading or writing any of the content that was present in the file before you opened it -- you can only add new content to the end (and since you opened in read+write mode, you can re-read what you wrote and rewrite it, but you still can't get to the data before it).