# replace line in a file C++

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to find a way to replace a line, containing a string, in a file with a new line.

If the string is not present in the file, then append it to the file.

Can someone give a sample code?

EDIT : is there anyway if the line that i need to replace is at the end of the file?

Comment: i have tried the appending part. and also creating a new file and moving the contents of the old file to the new file except the line to be deleted. But thats too tideous. I need somethin that is simple and elegent. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211749/c-file-programming-replace-a-text-in-a-file-using-posix-calls/2211761#2211761

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100880/reading-and-appending-from-to-a-file-with-stdfstream

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007254/overwriting-data-in-a-c-file-using-fstream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I recognize that this is not the smartest way to do it, the following code reads *demo.txt* line by line and searches for the word *cactus* to replace it for *oranges* while writing the output to a secondary file named *result.txt*.

Don't worry, I saved some work for you. Read the comment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
  string search_string = "cactus";
  string replace_string = "oranges";
  string inbuf;
  fstream input_file("demo.txt", ios::in);
  ofstream output_file("result.txt");

  while (!input_file.eof())
  {
      getline(input_file, inbuf);

      int spot = inbuf.find(search_string);
      if(spot >= 0)
      {
         string tmpstring = inbuf.substr(0,spot);
         tmpstring += replace_string;
         tmpstring += inbuf.substr(spot+search_string.length(), inbuf.length());
         inbuf = tmpstring;
      }

      output_file << inbuf << endl;
  }

  //TODO: delete demo.txt and rename result.txt to demo.txt
  // to achieve the REPLACE effect.
}
```

Comment: thanks. What if all i needed was to replace the last 2 lines of a file completely with 2 new lines?

Comment: @Prasanth Sounds like a new question to me. You could read the entire file once to discover how many lines of text are in it. Then subtract this value by 2 and you'll know which lines you should replace. Read the file again stopping on the interesting lines numbers and do your magic.

Comment: This sounded as a good snippet, but with VS 2010 I got totally wrong behaviour (no compiler error). My history included C and am no C++ wizard yet, so I discovered that the find method is not used in a standard way. See my snippet below. Wonder what the C++ wizards are saying here. I have found no better snippet than this on SE, what was quite surprising.

Comment: This doesn't check the state of `input_file` _after_ `getline`. [Why is `iostream::eof()` inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks! Feel free to adjust the code on this 10 years old answer if you think its worth.

Answer (score 1):

To replace the last two lines in your file:

- Use `fopen()` to open the file
- Get the current file position with `fgetpos()`
- Store always the last two file position and read line by line
- When you've reached the end of the file: The lower position is where you have to position to with `fseek()`
- Now you can `fprintf()` your new lines to the file and close it with `fclose()` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the code by KarlPhilip is a good starting point (thanks), but did not work correctly according to the ">= 0". Comparing to "0" it is known for MS CString-types and in C#, etc, but it seems not to work properly with the STL. E.g. in VS 2010 (only release), the C++ code behaved wrong with this compare without throwing an error!

Here is a correction to C++ standards: If some wizards have improvements, please post them. I think, it is a very useful and important question/snippet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;    

int main() 
{   
   string search_string = "cactus";   
   string replace_string = "oranges";   
   string inbuf;
   // Todo: Check, if input_file exists before. 
   // Todo: Try/catch or check, if you have write access to the output file.
   fstream input_file("demo.txt", ios::in);   
   ofstream output_file("result.txt");

   while (!input_file.eof())   
   {
      getline(input_file, inbuf);
      size_t foundpos = inbuf.find(search_string);
      if(foundpos != std::string::npos)
      {
         string tmpstring = inbuf.substr(0,spot);
         tmpstring += replace_string;
         tmpstring += inbuf.substr(spot+search_string.length(), inbuf.length());
         inbuf = tmpstring;
      }

      output_file << inbuf << endl;   
   }

   //TODO: delete demo.txt and rename result.txt to demo.txt      
   // to achieve the REPLACE effect. 
}
```

I used the following replacement part inside the "if" from another SO question
(The code above only replace the first occurrence):

```
if(foundpos != std::string::npos)
   replaceAll(inbuf, search_string, replace_string); 

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418231/c-replace-part-of-a-string-with-another-string
//
void replaceAll(std::string& str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to) 
{
    size_t start_pos = 0;
    while((start_pos = str.find(from, start_pos)) != std::string::npos) 
    {
        size_t end_pos = start_pos + from.length();
        str.replace(start_pos, end_pos, to);
        start_pos += to.length(); // In case 'to' contains 'from', like replacing 'x' with 'yx'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the length of (or delete) a line in the middle of a file, you will have to re-write all the subsequent lines.

There's no way of simply deleting or inserting characters into an existing file.

Comment: i need to insert or delete contents from the end of the file. is that possible?

Comment: @Prasanth. That's called appending and truncating. Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Sorry, but this is perhaps not possible on Windows, but it is possible on BS2000 using ISAM files ! (sequential indexed files) :-)