# C++ Read file and replace

Tags: c++, readfile

I would like to read a file which has several lines, and then search for a specific line, if that line is found, I would like to replace that line with some other value, how do i do it?

### Here is what have now:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
  {
  string line;

  ifstream myfile( "file.txt" );

  if (myfile) 

    {
    while (getline( myfile, line ))  
      {
      if (line == "my_match")
        {
        //cout << "found";
        ... here i would like to replace "my_match" with some other value
        }
      }
    myfile.close();
    }
  else cout << "error";

  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: C++ is probably not the best tool for this particular job

Comment: This is very likely a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%2B%2B]+replace+line+in+file

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace line in a file C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499095/replace-line-in-a-file-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want comments on how to make the code neater, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is where you want to be.

Assuming you're working with standard input and output, and will do redirection and such in a different language: yes, what you're doing is a possible solution.  You're not telling us what you want to replace it with, but the following should do it fine:

```
if (line == "my match")
    std::cout << "my replacement\n";
else
    std::cout << line << '\n';
```

I'd say that the biggest problem with this is it not being very generic; if you only want to match a line depending on a more complicated predicate, you're best off writing a dedicated function (or regex) for that; same for having the replacement depend on the line.  For example, in your loop you could have:

```
std::cout << make_replacement(line);
```

And then you could define:

```
std::string make_replacement(std::string const& line) {
    // some logic to construct a new string based on the line
}
```

Note that this makes a copy for each line, though, which may be expensive (depends on requirements and file size).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Paul - Perl is good:

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl -i.bak

  while (<>) {
     if (/^my_match$/) {
        print "replaced_line\n";
     } else {
        print "$_";
     }
  }
```

The `-i.bak` will automatically replace the file you're reading, and create a backup with a `.bak` extension.

[sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) is better:

```
sed -i 's/^my_match$/replace_text/' file.txt
```

However, in C, why not write your lines to stdout, rather than rewriting the file. Then use file directions / bash to write the new file?

If you *must* do it in C++, reading into memory then writing out is one option (assuming your file won't ever be too big):

```
  #include <string>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <vector>

  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
    string line;
    vector<string> buffer;

    ifstream in( "file.txt" );
    while (getline(in, line)) {
        buffer.push_back( (line == "my_match") ? "REPLACED" : line );
     }
     in.close();

     ofstream out("file.txt");
     for (vector<string>::iterator it = buffer.begin(); it!=buffer.end(); it++) {
        out << *it << endl;
     }

    return 0;
  }
```

If your file might be too big, you will need to write to a temporary file, then delete the original file and rename the temporary.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file line by line to a vector. Change the line you want to change and then delete the original file, create a new one and write everything back.