# Replace a line in text file

Tags: c++, stream, ifstream

I want to replace a line of text in a file, but I don't know a functions to do this.

**I have this:**

```
ofstream outfile("text.txt");
ifstream infile("text.txt");

infile >> replace with other text;
```

Any answers for this?

I miss to say, for add text in Some line in the file...

**Example**

```
infile.add(text, line);
```

Does C++ have functions for this?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499095/replace-line-in-a-file-c

Comment: Is this homework? If so please tag it, otherwise I would suggest a scripting language like perl or python, or just using `sed`.

Comment: No, no for homework, its for some work...

Comment: @Warkanlock any especial reason for using C++?

Comment: @AntonioPérez Yeah, SDL, Engines, Games, its a requeried for the Game developed in the industry

Answer (score 13):

I'm afraid you'll probably have to rewrite the entire file. Here is how you could do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string strReplace = "HELLO";
    string strNew = "GOODBYE";
    ifstream filein("filein.txt"); //File to read from
    ofstream fileout("fileout.txt"); //Temporary file
    if(!filein || !fileout)
    {
        cout << "Error opening files!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    string strTemp;
    //bool found = false;
    while(filein >> strTemp)
    {
        if(strTemp == strReplace){
            strTemp = strNew;
            //found = true;
        }
        strTemp += "\n";
        fileout << strTemp;
        //if(found) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input-file:

```
ONE
TWO
THREE
HELLO
SEVEN
```

Output-file:

```
ONE
TWO
THREE
GOODBYE
SEVEN
```

Just uncomment the commented lines if you only want it to replace the first occurance. Also, I forgot, in the end add code that deletes filein.txt and renames fileout.txt to filein.txt.

Comment: You can avoid a potential allocation (and save a line) by replacing `strTemp += "\n"; fileout << strTemp;` with `fileout << strTemp << '\n';`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to [seek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/seekg/) to the correct line/char/position in the file and then over-[write](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/). There is no function to search and replace as such (that I know of).

Comment: Mmm yes, seekg and seekp

      infile.seekg(20*i, ios::beg);
      infile.read(cad, 20);

No?

Comment: This won't work if the replacement text is not exactly the same size in bytes as what it replaces.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to replace text in a file, or add lines in the middle of a file, is to rewrite the *entire file* from the point of the first modification.  You cannot "make space" in the middle of a file for new lines.

The *reliable* way to do this is to copy the file's contents to a new file, making the modifications as you go, and then use `rename` to overwrite the old file with the new one.

Comment: To follow the strategy to create a modified copy and then rename it with original name it is noteworthy to copy the permissions and file attributes as well.