# Updating the Existing Specific record in txt File using C++

Tags: c++

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string file_name = "tableData.txt";
    ifstream userReadFile{ file_name };
    if (!userReadFile.is_open())
    {
        // The cerr object in C++ is used to print error messages.
        cerr << "Could not open input file: " << file_name << "\n\n";
        return 1;
    }

    int lastRecordNumber = 0;  // anticipating an empty file
    int a;
    string b, c, d;
    while (userReadFile >> a >> b >> c >> d) {
        lastRecordNumber = a;
    }
    userReadFile.close();

    // Open file for output.
    ofstream userWriteFile(file_name, ios::app);
    if (!userWriteFile.is_open())
    {
        cerr << "Could not open output file: " << file_name << "\n\n";
        return 2;
    }

    string firstName, userName, password;
    bool inputMore = true;
    while (inputMore)
    {
        // Input record from user.
        cout << "Input Data" << endl;
        cout << "Name: ";
        cin >> firstName;
        cout << "User-Name: ";
        cin >> userName;
        cout << "Password: ";
        cin >> password;
        cout << endl;

        userWriteFile
            << ++lastRecordNumber
            << ' ' << firstName
            << '\t' << userName
            << '\t' << password
            << '\n';

//        for (;;)
        while(inputMore)
        {
            cout << "Do You Want more Entries or Not (Press the Key Y(Yes) / N(No)): ";
            char character;
            cin >> character;
            cout << '\n';
            if (character == 'y' || character == 'Y') {
                inputMore = true;
                break;  // break out of the for-loop
            }
            else if (character == 'n' || character == 'N') {
                inputMore = false;
                break;  // break out of the for-loop
            }
            else {
                cout << "Invalid Character\n\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Now we close the output file.
    userWriteFile.close();

    // Open the file for input.
    userReadFile.open(file_name);
    if (!userReadFile.is_open())
    {
        cerr << "Could not open input file: " << file_name << "\n\n";
        return 3;
    }

    while (userReadFile >> a >> b >> c >> d) {
        cout << a << ". " << b << "  " << c << "  " << d << "\n\n";
    }
    userReadFile.close();
    
    
    // open file to read the content for Updating record
    userReadFile.open(file_name);
    int input;
    cout << "Input the id that you wish to find" << endl;
    cin >> input;

    cout << "\n";
    while(userReadFile >> a >> b >> c >> d)
    {
       if (input == a) {
         cout << a << ". " << b << "  " << c << "  " << d << "\n\n";
        }
    }
    
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "The user to update is as follow" << endl;
    userReadFile.close();
    // open file to write the updated record
    
    
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

Presently i can write and read the data. Now i want to update the content having specific id
i.e,
1. sam  samcodeonline sam@32
if in the first compilation i have added this record. In the second compilation i would select this record through the user id which in this case is 1. I am successfully getting the data through the user id .

now the problem i am facing is that when i try to update (append or trunicate) , it in the case of append adds the data to the existing file in the last of it and in the case of trunication it erase the data from the whole file and add that specific data.

Now what should i do in order to update the data in that specific line and then update it in the file so that it can then write and read the updated data in the next compilation.

Comment: the simple way is to read all the file into memory make the modification, then write all the contents to the file. The more complicated way is most of the time just too complicated.

Comment: Couple hours? You got to alter your expectations of your productivity.  Some file handling tasks can easily take days or more at that level of skill.

Comment: Just use sed to [search-and-replace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11245501/4165552). Or load the file to the memory, [modify it, and then write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4499386/4165552). All necessary resources appear on top of google search, so I would say you didn't try to research the topic yourself before dropping your code to SO.

Comment: You can't insert or remove anything in the middle of a file, you can only overwrite (and a "line" is not something that exists at the file level).

Comment: by overwritting, can i achieve the task at hand. @molbdnilo

Comment: @sarimnadeem That would require redesigning your data (using fixed-size records) and not using text files for storage. It will probably take a couple of days, after you have studied how to do it and practiced on simpler data.

Comment: @molbdnilo is there any approach in which we can modify the existing file and place the changes to the other file (the trunication approach).

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has all the pieces necessary, but to be frank the code is very complicated for what it is doing. One reason for that is the absence of a data structure to represent the data you are reading. Define it:

```
struct person {
    std::string firstName;
    std::string userName;
    std::string password;
};
```

Next, you are mixing logic with io in `main`. Your code will be much simpler if you separate it. First step would be to overload io operators for the above struct:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&,person&);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,person&);
```

Implement them, make sure what is written by `<<` can be correctly read by `>>` and vice versa.

Next factor that would help to untangle io from logic is to read all the file contents into memory so you can work on them independently of code reading or writing them. I suggest to use a

```
 std::vector<person> persons;
```

Code to read would look like this (error handling omitted):

```
 person p;
 while(infile >> p) persons.push_back(p);
```

Writing is similarly simple:

```
 for (const auto& p : persons) outfile << p << "\n";
```

Once you have that, modifying i-th line in the file will be as simple as:

```
 persons[i].password = "1234";
```

You can then read all file contents, modify some of it, write back all contents.

Modifying only selected parts of a file is much more compilcated, so you only want to do it once the file becomes too big to be kept in memory. And even then you should consider to read it in chunks, modify the chunks, write back the chunks (ie basically again: read it all, modify, write it all).

Comment: yeah, your solution would be the good approach to tackle the problem. But it was my task assigned by my senior developer to use the functional programming only to solve this problem, without the use of dataStructure and OOP @463035818_is_not_an_ai

Comment: Pure functional programming in C++? Or did he ask to just use functions?

Comment: @sarimnadeem there is no OOP in this answer. Using data structures != object orientation. It is unclear what you mean.

Comment: pure functional programming @kiner_shah

Comment: @sarimnadeem the code in your question is not pure functional programming either. I think you misunderstood something about your task. Anyhow, if there are special requirements you should mention them in the question.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai let me put the things straight the task was to take the data from the user , which would include its firstName , userName and password. and as the code would read the file it should increment in the file so that the sequence of users remains the same i.e, 1 , 2 ,3, and so on.  now is the turn to update the data and then delete it. i have get the user data through the id of the user but i am unable to update it where it originally exists. I am into this task for nearly a week now, use of oop and datastructure is curbed i can't use those. neither it is pure functional.

Comment: you provided a straight forward solution to it which as a beginner was not that easy to comprehend for sure. @463035818_is_not_an_ai . but i am thankful that you tried to assist.

Comment: @sarimnadeem "use of oop and datastructure is curbed i can't use those" sorry, but that does not make sense. `std::string` is a data structure. C++ streams are one place in the standard library that does make use of OOP. THere is not more OOP and datastructures in this answer than there is in your code. Anyhow, `operator<<` I suggest is just a free function, if you are not allowed to use it like this , simply make it a free function `void read(istream&,std::string&,std::string&,std::string&)` to read 3 strings, do the same for `>>`.

Comment: @sarimnadeem ...And if you are not allowed to use `std::vector` or an array, then you must reread your lecture materials, because your teacher must have told you about something else you need to use to solve the task. We cannot know that, we do not have the notes from your lecture

Comment: @sarimnadeem You should edit the question to clarify the requirements.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai try to run the provided code in your compiler. you would get to know everything . As this is the whole code that till now i have wrote. Was intimidating to write it at first place and now to change that is taking more mental strength.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai is there a way to make the amendments to the provided code to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: @sarimnadeem take a break. problems seem to be about stuff that no SO answer can help with. After the break I suggest you to talk to your instructor. Usually thats the best one to ask when you do not understand a task given to you